# FileNotFoundError, os.getcwd() returns file name not a directory

Tags: python-3.x, file-not-found

I have a program which attempts to read a file, if it can read the file it will generate a list from that file and return a random selection from that list to the user. If the file cna't be found, or there is another error a message will alert the user and the program will default to using a default list within the source code of my program.

I pass the first part of the file name from one function to a readFile() function which appends '.txt' to the file name it was passed and tries to read one of three files, depending on the name the function was given.

Despite the files existing, and I've displayed hidden extensions to make sure there not called .txt.txt, the program is still returning a FileNotFoundError

Searching online, I've heard mention of os.getcwd() so I ran print(os.getcwd()) at the start of my readFile() function and what was returned was all.txt; "all" being the value I passed to readFile() to perform this test.

So I believe the file, in this case all.txt can't be found, becuase the program's working directory within this function is set to the fileName rather than the program directory.

How can I solve this problem?

Below is the function which passes the file name, not including extension to the readFile() function; there are multiple options, I've just included the first one to improve readability on here, all options return the same error, and behave in the same way.

```
def generateActivity() :

chores = ['Washing Up', 'Laundry']
fun = ['Watch TV', 'Play a game']

allActivities = chores + fun
print(allActivities)

if menu() == 'R' :

    try :
       allList = readFile('all')
       displayOutput(random.choice(allList))

    except FileNotFoundError :
        print('Sorry, all activities list, file not found')
        print('Using default all activities list...\n')
        displayOutput(random.choice(allActivities))

    except :
        print('Sorry there was an error with all.txt')
        print('Using default all activities list...\n')
        displayOutput(random.choice(allActivities))
```

This is the readFile() function.

```
def readFile(list) : 

print(os.getcwd())

READ = 'r'
fileName = list + '.txt'

with open(fileName, READ) as f :
    # Reads the entire file
    dictionary = f.readlines() 

# Seperates each word to create a list of words
Activitylist = [word.strip() for word in dictionary] 

return(ActivityList)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `input()` instead of `def readFile(list)`.

Here is an optional code for you to use if I understood you correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
1. Read a file.
1a. If file can be read, generate a list from that file.
1b. Return a random selection from that list to the user.
'''

'''
2. If file cannot be read or error: alert user with message
2a. Use default list.
'''

import os
import pathlib
import random

#Print the current working directory to check if path is correct.

cwd = os.getcwd()
print("This is the directory the desired file is located: " + cwd)

#Request input from user for name of file. 

file_desired = input() + '.txt'

#Use pathlib to set path of the file. 

path = pathlib.Path('write_full_path_to_directory_here' + file_desired)
print(path)

#If the path of the file exists, use list from file.

if path.is_file():
    with open (file_desired, 'r') as file_wanted:
        print("File is available.")
        dictionary = file_wanted.readlines()
        Activitylist = [word.strip() for word in dictionary]
        print(random.choice(Activitylist))

#If file path does not exist, then use default list.

else:
    print('Sorry, all activities list, file not found')
    print('Using default all activities list...\n')

    chores = ['Washing Up', 'Laundry']
    fun = ['Watch TV', 'Play a game']

    allActivities = chores + fun

    print(random.choice(allActivities))
```

Hope that helps!

Omneya

Comment: Thank you for the input @Omneya